# show on click but click anywhere else to hide

Tags: jquery

I am creating a tooltip. I want the user to click on a link to display the tooltip, and then click anywhere else to hide it. Or if they click on another tooltip on the page, the current one should hide and the new one would show.

Here is my current code..

```
$(".byr").click(function () {
            $(".popup").hide();
            $(this).find(".popup").show();
        });
```

The problem with this current code is if I open a tooltip, there is no way to close it, unless I open a new one, but then can't close that...

I also want the user to click anywhere on the page to close. Thanks

Sorry guys forgot to put a link to the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wtkmL

Comment: You could register a click handler on the whole document using `.once()` that would close any popup.

Comment: There are so many lightweight, compatibility tested, tooltip plugins out there. Why recreate the wheel?

Comment: Sorry guys forgot to put a link to the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wtkmL

Answer (score 0):

Try this : bind `click` event to `document` instead of link and check if clicked element is link or not.

```
   $(document).click(function (e) {
        //close popup
        $(".popup").hide();
        //check if clicked element has class byr
        if(e.target.className.indexOf('byr')!=-1)
         $(this).find(".popup").show();
    });
```